# Multi module project with maven (jpa+spring+root project)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I have done 2 projects in eclipse: JPA and Spring. I need to connect it with Maven but I have no idea  how to add existing modules to new parent module. I tried to do it adding  modules tag to my main module and parent tag to other but I can`t compile it correctly.

CODE:
I have 3 project frontend (jpa project), model (spring project) and root (only pom.xml file)

b2b:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>b2b</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.0.17</thymeleaf.version>
    </properties>
    <description>View module for b2b</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Thymeleaf -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.183949</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>model</groupId> <artifactId>model</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>res.laudp</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <parent>
        <groupId>res.laudp</groupId>
        <artifactId>b2b-root</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <name>b2b</name>
    <groupId>res.laudp</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

model:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>model</artifactId>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernatespatial</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>res.laudp</groupId>
        <artifactId>b2b-root</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <name>model</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <groupId>res.laudp</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

b2b-root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>res.laudp</groupId>
    <artifactId>b2b-root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Root module</name>
    <description>It's a root project for whole project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernatespatial</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE
        </org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <modules>
        <module>../b2b</module>
        <module>../model</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why didn't you add the other project as your artifact?

Comment: What do you mean? How can I do this? I am noob, I saw only this method.

Comment: whats the happens if you try "mvn package" in the parent folder?

Comment: please share your directory structure, and what exception you get when you say you can't compile it?